# Python Array, trying to place text file into an array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, arraylist

I am trying to complete a piece of coursework so need to place a text file full of key words into an array when i do it i get a type error message saying:

> TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not list

What does this mean?

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

array = []
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
  for line in f:
    array.append(line)
print array

searchfile =open('test.txt','r')
for line in searchfile:
    if array in line: print line
searchfile.close()
```

**EDIT:** Thank you for the reply i have changed the line to display this:

```
searchfile =open('test.txt','r')
for line in searchfile:
    if line in array: print line
searchfile.close()
```

The search works except i have a keywords document containing simple words like 'green, blue etc' (all on their own line) i then have a document with text such as 'my shirt is green' when i use this code it wont find anything but if i change the sentence to just a word it will find it. i need it to search a document for keywords and then display the whole line that it was in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that you're attempting to check whether a list is in a string, with this line:

```
if array in line:
```

My guess is you're attempting to check if the line is in `array`, so your `in` statement must be reversed:

```
if line in array:
```

So that you aren't confused by errors like this in the future, note that `in` is an [operator](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm). The *left operand* is whatever object that is to the left of your operator which is part of the `in` operation. From there, it's pretty clear if you look at types what the error is indicating.

Comment: hi thankyou for the reply i have changed the line to display this: 
searchfile =open('test.txt','r')
for line in searchfile:
 if line in array: print line
searchfile.close() The search works except i have a keywords document containing simple words like 'green, blue etc' (all on their own line) i then have a document with text such as 'my shirt is green' when i use this code it wont find anything but if i change the sentence to just a word it will find it. i need it to search a document for keywords and then display the whole line that it was in.

Comment: Well good luck with that! Look into splitting lines on whitespaces so you could iterate over each word, or using the regex module.

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

array = []
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
  for line in f:
    array.append(line)
print array

searchfile =open('test.txt','r')
for line in searchfile:
    if line in array: print line
searchfile.close()
```

Should work now.

```
if line in array:
```

Is the changed line, now searches in `array` for the `line` as opposed to checking if the array is in the line (which it wont be).

**EDIT:**
Forgot this bit...
The error is because you are searching a string for a list, and this will cause an error as a list can't be contained in a string. [TypeError's](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.TypeError) are raised when an operation is applied to the wrong type. This error is python telling you you can't search a string for a list.

**EDIT 2**
In respose to your edit you need to split the lines of the file by a space `" "`, and then iterate over that.

```
array = []
with open("words.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        array.append(line)
        print array

searchfile =open('sent.txt','r')
for line in searchfile:
    sLine = line.split(" ")
    for word in sLine:
        if word in array:
            print line
searchfile.close()
```

This now iterates through each line in the file and then splits and saves the line as a new list - `sLine`. Each item of this list is then checked against `array`.

There is however a bug in this, if the word you are searching for isn't at the end of the line it wont be found, since each item in `array` contains a `\n`, but some in `searchfile` may not.

```
array = []
with open("words.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip("\n")
    array.append(line)
print array

searchfile =open('sent.txt','r')
for line in searchfile:
    sLine = line.split(" ")
    for word in sLine:
        word = word.rstrip("\n")
        if word in array:
            print line,
searchfile.close()
```

This will now find the word even if it is embedded in a sentence.

e.g.

array - cat

searchfile - the cat sat on the mat

cat will now be found even though it is in the sentence.

The comma on the end of the print should stop there being a line in between each line you print out.

Comment: Why add a nearly identical answer?

Comment: hi thankyou for the reply i have changed the line to display this: 
searchfile =open('test.txt','r')
for line in searchfile:
 if line in array: print line
searchfile.close() The search works except i have a keywords document containing simple words like 'green, blue etc' (all on their own line) i then have a document with text such as 'my shirt is green' when i use this code it wont find anything but if i change the sentence to just a word it will find it. i need it to search a document for keywords and then display the whole line that it was in.